# How to add a field's value to a url in firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

im having a javascript compatibility problem. This code works in Chrome but not in Firefox. The sentence it's using a value from search-text and adding it to the search url.

```
<a href="" onClick="this.href='http://localhost:8000/search?q='+search_text.value">
    <input type="button" id="search-button" value="search"/>
</a>
```

If i delete the + operator it works on firefox too:

```
<a href="" onClick="this.href='http://localhost:8000/search?q='">
    <input type="button" id="search-button" value="search"/>
</a>
```

So my question is: How can i add a value from a field to the url on firefox? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't use inline Javascript!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a button inside a link. This *will* cause inconsistances between browsers. **[Use a validator](http://validator.w3.org)**

Comment: @Quentin: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-changes

Comment: @elclanrs — You appear to have found an error in that Note. The [actual specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) says "Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant."

Comment: I note that the [page on input type="button"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html#input.button) in that Note *does* say "The interactive element input must not appear as a descendant of the a element."

Comment: @Quentin: You're right, what I found seems a bit misleading because you'd assume "inline" means _any_ inline element, such as inputs. It does make sense that it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, thanks for the help! (i'll fix it Nile, im testing this code from a workmate.)

```
<input type="button" id="boton-busqueda" value="Buscar" onClick="location.href='http://localhost:8000/search?q='+buscador_texto.value"/>
```